# Generate random names with arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I want to generate random 20.000 names.
I have 3 arrays: $firstNameCollection, $middleNameCollection and $lastNameCollection like this: (view code), and i want to generate (random) 20.000 names. I will attach my code, where generate only 1 name..

```
$firstNameCollection = array("Harry","Ross",
                        "Bruce","Cook",
                        "Carolyn","Morgan",
                        "Albert","Walker",
                        "Randy","Reed",
                        "Larry","Barnes",
                        "Lois","Wilson",
                        "Jesse","Campbell",
                        "Ernest","Rogers",
                        "Theresa","Patterson",
                        "Henry","Simmons",
                        "Michelle","Perry",
                        "Frank","Butler",
                        "Shirley");

$middleNameCollection = array("Brooks",
                    "Rachel","Edwards",
                    "Christopher","Perez",
                    "Thomas","Baker",
                    "Sara","Moore",
                    "Chris","Bailey",
                    "Roger","Johnson",
                    "Marilyn","Thompson",
                    "Anthony","Evans",
                    "Julie","Hall",
                    "Paula","Phillips",
                    "Annie","Hernandez",
                    "Dorothy","Murphy",
                    "Alice","Howard");

$lastNameCollection = array("Ruth","Jackson",
                    "Debra","Allen",
                    "Gerald","Harris",
                    "Raymond","Carter",
                    "Jacqueline","Torres",
                    "Joseph","Nelson",
                    "Carlos","Sanchez",
                    "Ralph","Clark",
                    "Jean","Alexander",
                    "Stephen","Roberts",
                    "Eric","Long",
                    "Amanda","Scott",
                    "Teresa","Diaz",
                    "Wanda","Thomas");

$newFirstName = $firstNameCollection[rand(0, count($firstNameCollection)-1)];
$newMiddleName = $middleNameCollection[rand(0, count($middleNameCollection)-1)];
$newLastName = $lastNameCollection[rand(0, count($lastNameCollection)-1)];

$fullNameCollection = array();
$fullNameCollection[] = $newFirstName." ".$newMiddleName." ".$newLastName;
```

If i print it with "echo $fullNameCollection" it will give me only 1 name... So.. How can i make 20.000 names? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for providing prebuilt PHP arrays of random names!

Comment: I second Iwitzel. I was searching the web for a list random names as strings separated by commas. I thought I had to write a new program to do that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop

```
$fullNameCollection = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 20000;$i++) {
    $newFirstName = $firstNameCollection[rand(0, count($firstNameCollection)-1)];
    $newMiddleName = $middleNameCollection[rand(0, count($middleNameCollection)-1)];
    $newLastName = $lastNameCollection[rand(0, count($lastNameCollection)-1)];

    $fullNameCollection[] = $newFirstName." ".$newMiddleName." ".$newLastName;
}
```

If you want to output all names you can e.g.

```
foreach($fullNameCollection as $name) {
    echo $name;
}
```

With only unique names

```
$fullNameCollection = array();
while(count($fullNameCollection) <= 20000) {
    $newFirstName = $firstNameCollection[rand(0, count($firstNameCollection)-1)];
    $newMiddleName = $middleNameCollection[rand(0, count($middleNameCollection)-1)];
    $newLastName = $lastNameCollection[rand(0, count($lastNameCollection)-1)];


    $name = $newFirstName." ".$newMiddleName." ".$newLastName;

    if(!in_array($name, $fullNameCollection)) {
         $fullNameCollection[] = $name;
    }
}
```

**Note**: this loop can be endless if there are not enough possibility's for unique names.
If you want all combinations it would be better to not use a random function

Comment: More 1 little question. How can i print all random names, but to be all different. (I know with function in_array...but i dont know to use it)

Comment: @ColarPaul should it then still be 20000 ?

Comment: Yes. 20.000 names i need.

Comment: can you help me with something more, please?

Comment: @ColarPaul sure, but you need to open a new question. this comment section is not for this (:

Comment: If i make the same problem, but with for function how should be in max 20000 random names?

for($i=0; $i<30; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<30; $j++){
     for($k=0; $k<30; $k++){
      $fullNameCollection[] = $firstNameCollection[$i]." ".$middleNameCollection[$j]." ".$lastNameCollection[$k];
     }
    }
   }

this will show me 27 000 names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you need a `for` loop around your code?

```
$fullNameCollection = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < 20000; $x++) {
    $newFirstName = $firstNameCollection[rand(0, count($firstNameCollection)-1)];
    $newMiddleName = $middleNameCollection[rand(0, count($middleNameCollection)-1)];
    $newLastName = $lastNameCollection[rand(0, count($lastNameCollection)-1)];


    $fullNameCollection[$x] = $newFirstName." ".$newMiddleName." ".$newLastName;
}
```